# Où placer le « en » de « en avoir besoin » dans une phrase au futur proche ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, ordre-des-mots

Comment doit-on utiliser le verbe « avoir besoin de » dans une conjugaison au futur proche ?

Par exemple :

> Est-ce que tu as besoin de compétences linguistique ?
>
> 1. Je en vais avoir besoin.
> 2. Je vais en avoir besoin.
> 3. Je vais avoir en besoin.

Quelle est la position correcte de « en » ?

Answer (score 3):

Excepté dans les cas particuliers des questions et de l'impératif, les pronoms objet ou complément se placent toujours juste avant le verbe auquel ils se rapportent. Y compris lorsqu'il s'agit d'un verbe à l'infinitif qui suit un autre verbe.

Ici il ne s'agit pas d'« en aller » mais d'« en avoir besoin », on écrit donc :

> Je vais en avoir besoin.

D'autres exemples :

> Je voudrais en reprendre. (Reprendre des choses, ou Reprendre de quelque chose)
>
> Je viens d'en acheter. (Acheter des choses)
>
> Il peut espérer en trouver au marché. (Trouver des choses)
>
> J'en entends crier. (Entendre des personnes)
>
> Il a cru en voir sortir. (Voir des choses ou des personnes)
>
> Il pensait en avoir oublié. (Avoir oublié des choses, infinitif passé)
>
> Il voulait en être averti. (Être averti de quelque chose, forme passive)

Mais attention aux constructions causatives (*faire* joue ici le rôle d'un auxiliaire) :

> Il peut en faire construire.
>
> J'en ai fait venir.

Answer (score -5):

Il s'agit de la seconde proposition. Ici "en" est un adverbe et un adverbe est toujours au milieu dans la conjugaison d'un temps composé.

Comment: Non seulement le « en » de cette phrase est un pronom, mais en plus le verbe n’est pas composé ; en outre, ta remarque sur la position de « en » dans un verbe composé est fausse. « J’en ai eu besoin ».